# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jstl, el

I am getting an error in JSP and I cannot figure out what is causing it. I have included all of the appropriate libraries and I've made sure to follow bean convention on uppercase/lowercase. Here's the relevant code in the JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${relevantData}" var="entry">
     <p>${entry.price}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

The `relevantData` was a `List<MyData>`. For the purposes of this question it is sufficent to say `MyData` is a class that contains a `Double` named price (with a Getter and Setter following the bean convention). When I try to load this page I receive the following error in the server logs (Tomcat 7.0.22):

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: 
Property 'price' not readable on type java.lang.Double
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: accessor methods are public, is MyData inner class ?

Comment: The accessor methods are all public. The class itself was not public.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was actually caused by the visibility of the `MyData` class. I had auto-generated the `MyData` class in Netbeans but I did not notice that there was no keyword `public` in front of the class name. This meant that by the time it got to the JSP there was no way for it to read the properties in `MyData`.

I changed the type to `public` and the problem was solved.

Comment: I run into the exact same problem. moved type to new file, but forget to add public... thanks!

Comment: doh, I should have been able to figure this one out ! Thanks for this post!

Comment: This issue also arised after I used UCDectector to delete unnecessary code in eclipse. As the program was unable to interpret the JSTL-code, it suggested that I changed the modifier of the class to "default", and I did. Thanks for the help to locate my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took me the whole day checking getter name; but I was blind to check the class visibility :(